# Spring AOP setAdvice only on one specific Method

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, aop, spring-aop

I have the following class:

```
package x.y.z;

public class MyClass{
public void someMethod(SomeObject object){
//do somethinng
}

public void {
//do somethinng
}

}
```

Now I would like to set `@PointCut`only on method `someMethod(SomeObject object, int param1)`

How can I do it?

**Update** I'm trying

```
@Pointcut("execution(x.y.z.MyClass.someMethod(x.y.z.SomeObject))") but I'm getting not well formed pointcut exception.
```

Comment: Can't you just make the pointcut explicitly name that method rather than using a wildcard?

Comment: @Dave, how can I do it? This is exactly my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Point cut should be:

```
target(x.y.z.MyClass) && execution(<RETURN TYPE> someMethod(x.y.z.SomeObject))
```

Answer (score 4):

Attach AspectJ to your classpath and use maven AOP plugin to compile this Aspect to bytecode, look at this example:

```
@Aspect
public class IOControlAspect {
    @Around("execution(com...SomeClass.someMethod(*))")
    public Object ioControlWrapper(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        {your code here}
        return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, but which methos will it execute I have methods with same name and different parameters.

Comment: Its OK, you can use execution(com...SomeClass.someMethod(int, java.lang.String, etc.)) to specify parameters

Comment: I don't remember if Spring AOP supports this notation but AspectJ can work with it.

Comment: If you were doing `return pjp.proceed();` then you'd be better using `@Before` advice and a simpler method. (I prefer to use annotations to mark intercepted methods, but that's a bit more intrusive on the intercepted code.)

Answer (score 1):

**Suppose we have a @Controller class :**

```
package co.gg.controller;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @GetMapping(value="/getTenantRoles")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getTenantRoles(@RequestParam("tenant_id") String tenant_id) throws SQLException {

        sqlConnection = con.makeconnection(dbName, dbPort, dbUserName, dbPass, dbHost);

        String sql = "select * from tenant_role where tenant_id = "+tenant_id+" and is_active = 1 and is_deleted = 0;";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = sqlConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<TenantRoleModel> tenantRoleModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next()) {
            TenantRoleModel currentModel = new TenantRoleModel(
                                                                    rs.getInt("tenant_role_id"),
                                                                    rs.getInt("is_deleted"),
                                                                    rs.getInt("is_active"),
                                                                    rs.getInt("tenant_id"),
                                                                    rs.getString("role_name"),
                                                                    rs.getString("create_date")
                                                                );

            tenantRoleModelList.add(currentModel);
        }

        return new Gson().toJson(tenantRoleModelList);
    }
}
```

**Then We have to intercept that method like this:**

```
package co.gg.AOP;


@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class Aspects {

    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* co.fdbk.controller.LoginController.getTenantRoles(..))", returning = "result")
    public void afterAPICall(JoinPoint joinPoint,Object result){

        System.out.println("AOP Method Name :"+ joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("AOP Return Value  :"+ result);


    }
}
```

***This is how we can intercept specific method.***